# Curl fails after following 50 redirects but wget works fine

Tags: php, redirect, curl, web-crawler, wget

I have an experimental PHP based web crawler and I noticed that it cannot read some pages, for example on some particular domains curl says it failed after following 50 redirects but wget reads that same domain just fine:

`curl 'netflix.com' -L -o 'output.txt'`

**Result:**

`curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed`

No data in output.txt file.

**While this command works fine:**

`wget netflix.com`

Any ideas on what can cause this? I doubt that remote server handles requests based on the two different user agents.

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of curl (probably by design)

Comment: I'd guess because wget enables cookies by default but you didn't tell curl to use cookies...

Comment: @DanielStenberg that was it, if you can add it as an answer I will pick it. Thanks.

Comment: Good guess @DanielStenberg.  I updated my answer, hopefully you will answer and get credit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably because you didn't tell curl to use cookies, which it doesn't do unless you ask it to - while wget enables them by default.

Use the [--cookie](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-b) or [--cookie-jar](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-c) options to enable cookies.

Answer (score 10):

`--max-redirs N` is the option used to limit the number of redirects.  The default, as stated, is 50.

The "47" you see there is the error code for hitting the limit of redirects.

The redirect limit for `wget` is 20, by default, so there is definitely something else going on as the redirect for curl is higher.

The run on my system for the same command works fine, and only has about 3 - 5 redirects.

You could use the `--verbose` option to track what those redirects are and perhaps compare them to the default output from `wget`.

Cookies are enabled by default on `wget`, and not with `curl`, as reminded by @DanielStenberg so hopefully he will answer and be accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I did tried --verbose later and I seen a funny url named **"Entry Trap"** https://signup.netflix.com/entrytrap it was a cookie problem, once I told Curl to use cookies it worked fine.

Comment: DanielStenberg's guess was very accurate, if he will not add it as an answer I will pick yours. The --verbose did helped. Thanks.